# Proving that addition on $\mathbb{Z}$ is associative

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading a book that constructs the integers as follows:

> For every $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\neq 0$, we select a new symbol represented as $(-n)$ and we define the set of integers:
>   $$\mathbb{Z} = \{-n:n\in\mathbb{N},n\neq 0\}\cup\mathbb{N}.$$
>   We define the adition on $\mathbb{Z}$ as:
>
> 1. If $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$, then if $y=0$, $x+y=x+0=x$, and if $y\neq 0, \exists b\in\mathbb{N}:b^+=y$, so that $x+y=x+b^+=(x+b)^+$.
> 2. $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}, x+0=0+x=x$.
> 3. If $m,n\in\mathbb{N} ,$ and $ m,n\neq 0$, such that $m=n+k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$, we define:
>
>    - $m+(-n)=(-n)+m=k.$
>    - $(-m)+n = n+(-m) = \cases{-k & if $k\neq 0$, \\ 0 & if $k=0$.}$
>    - $(-m)+(-n) = -(m+n)$
>
> Note that given $x,y$ where at least one of them is not a natural number, then the three items above define $x+y$.

I'm having trouble with proving the associativity of the addition on $\mathbb{Z}$. It seems as though I can't use induction (because I'm not checking a property on $\mathbb{N}$). So the method I chose to prove this was by contradiction. Given $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$ I suppose that $(x+y)+z\neq x+(y+z)$. I'll prove one case. If neither of $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$, then there are $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x,y,z=-a,-b,-c$. Therefore 
$$(x+y)+z = ((-a)+(-b))+(-c) = -(a+b)+(-c) = -((a+b)+c)\\=-(a+(b+c)) = x+(y+z)\text{, contradiction!}$$

Now I continue with, for instance, the case in which $z\in\mathbb{N}\wedge x,y\notin\mathbb{N}$. Then
$$(x+y)+z = -(a+b)+z =\pm k,$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ where $\pm k = k,-k,0$ depending on the relation ($<,>,=$) between $a+b$ and $c$. But
$$x+(y+z) = -a+(-b+z) = -a+(-b+a+b\pm k) = (-a)+(a\pm k).$$

Here I'd like to cancell $-a+a=0$, but it turns out that I can't because $(-a)$ is not a natural number.

So my question is: is there any easier way to prove the associativity of integers? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first bullet point under (3) says that $(-a)+(a+k)=k$. If you’re dealing with $(-a)+(a-k)$, and $a-k\in\Bbb N$, then $a=(a-k)+k$, and the second bullet point gives you $-k$. If you’re dealing with $(-a)+(a-k)$, and $a-k\notin\Bbb N$, show that $a-k=-(k-a)$, and use the third bullet point. With such a complex definition by cases, I doubt that you’ll find a very nice way to prove associativity.